# Parsing JSON with nested Arrays

Tags: java, json, parsing, permissions, nested

So I tried by the way of my last question but I only got problems and more problems with it. I try to parse this.

```
[
   {

   },
   {
      "Cliente0":[
         {
            "codrefcli":"1541121"
         },
         {
            "razonsocial":"Perico de los palotes"
         },
         {
            "cif":"45417265"
         },
         {
            "num":"964491837"
         },
         {
            "correo":"perico@yahoo.com"
         },
         {
            "direccion":"calle maria la vieja"
         },
         {
            "metodopago":"T"
         },
         {
            "observaciones":"que pesado"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "Empleado0":[
         {
            "codempleado":"1"
         },
         {
            "nombre":"Carlos"
         },
         {
            "apellidos":"Basilio"
         },
         {
            "dni":"15421451H"
         },
         {
            "direccion":"Calle el rio"
         },
         {
            "fechaalta":"2018-05-17"
         },
         {
            "copiacontrato":"aaa"
         },
         {
            "numcuenta":"884723877"
         }
      ]
   },
   {

   },
   {
      "PedidoCliente0":[
         {
            "numped":"454524"
         },
         {
            "fechapedido":"2018-05-09"
         },
         {
            "formapago":"Efectivo"
         },
         {
            "enviadoa":"Perico de los palotes"
         },
         {
            "codcliente":"1541121"
         },
         {
            "cpp":"5132413"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "PedidoProveedor0":[
         {
            "numped":"7455112"
         },
         {
            "fechapedido":"2018-05-01"
         },
         {
            "formapago":"Efectivo"
         },
         {
            "enviadoa":"Calle el marino"
         },
         {
            "codcliente":"10"
         },
         {
            "cpp":"4555424"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "Producto0":[
         {
            "crf":"4555424"
         },
         {
            "name":"Limpiador"
         },
         {
            "desc":"Producto de importacion italiano"
         },
         {
            "pve":"8.44"
         },
         {
            "pvp":"14.99"
         },
         {
            "cdp":"10"
         },
         {
            "familia":"Limpieza"
         },
         {
            "existencias":"10"
         }
      ],
      "Producto1":[
         {
            "crf":"5132413"
         },
         {
            "name":"Colador"
         },
         {
            "desc":"Colador de acero"
         },
         {
            "pve":"15"
         },
         {
            "pvp":"18"
         },
         {
            "cdp":"10"
         },
         {
            "familia":"Cocina"
         },
         {
            "existencias":"100"
         }
      ]
   },
   {

   },
   {
      "Proveedor0":[
         {
            "crf":"10"
         },
         {
            "razonsocial":"pene"
         },
         {
            "cif":"10"
         },
         {
            "num":"10"
         },
         {
            "correo":"10"
         },
         {
            "direccion":"10"
         },
         {
            "metodopago":"1"
         },
         {
            "observaciones":"10"
         }
      ],
      "Proveedor1":[
         {
            "crf":"5421452"
         },
         {
            "razonsocial":"Falete"
         },
         {
            "cif":"45411"
         },
         {
            "num":"42314"
         },
         {
            "correo":"falete@gmail.com"
         },
         {
            "direccion":"tu casa"
         },
         {
            "metodopago":"T"
         },
         {
            "observaciones":"Es muy pesado"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I get this JSON Generationg it by getting data from my database getting them with this code:

```
    import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

public class getdata extends dbconnect{

    public void getData() throws IOException {
        int i = 0;

        JSONArray listt = new JSONArray();

        JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject jobjt1 = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject jobjt2 = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject jobjt3 = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject jobjt4 = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject jobjt5 = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject jobjt6 = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject jobjt7 = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject jobjt8 = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject jobjt9 = new JSONObject();



        try {
            //Albaran
            String query1 = "select * from Albaran";
            rs = st.executeQuery(query1);
            i=0;
            while(rs.next()) {
                JSONArray list1 = new JSONArray();
                JSONObject jobja = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobjb = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobjc = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobjd = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobje = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobjf = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobjg = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobjh = new JSONObject();

                String a1= rs.getString("CodAlbaran");
                String a2= rs.getString("CodRefCli");
                String a3= rs.getString("CodRefPro");
                String a4= rs.getString("CIFPropio");
                String a5= rs.getString("Dir.Archivo");

                jobja.put("codalbaran", a1);
                jobjb.put("codRefCli", a2);
                jobjc.put("codrefpro",a3 );
                jobjd.put("cifpropio", a4);
                jobje.put("directorio", a5);                
                 list1.add(jobja);
                 list1.add(jobjb);
                 list1.add(jobjc);
                 list1.add(jobjd);
                 list1.add(jobje);

                 jobjt1.put("Albaran"+i++, list1);

            }
            listt.add(jobjt1);
            //Clientes
            String query2 = "select * from Clientes";
            rs = st.executeQuery(query2);
            i=0;
            while(rs.next()) {
                JSONArray list2 = new JSONArray();
                JSONObject jobja = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobjb = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobjc = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobjd = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobje = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobjf = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobjg = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobjh = new JSONObject();

                String b1 = rs.getString("CodRefCli");
                String b2 = rs.getString("RazonSocial");
                String b3 = rs.getString("CIF");
                String b4 = rs.getString("Num");
                String b5 = rs.getString("Correo");
                String b6 = rs.getString("Direccion");
                String b7 = rs.getString("MetodoPago");
                String b8 = rs.getString("Observaciones");

                 jobja.put("codrefcli", b1);
                 jobjb.put("razonsocial", b2);
                 jobjc.put("cif", b3);
                 jobjd.put("num", b4);
                 jobje.put("correo", b5);
                 jobjf.put("direccion", b6);
                 jobjg.put("metodopago", b7);
                 jobjh.put("observaciones", b8);
                 list2.add(jobja);
                 list2.add(jobjb);
                 list2.add(jobjc);
                 list2.add(jobjd);
                 list2.add(jobje);
                 list2.add(jobjf);
                 list2.add(jobjg);
                 list2.add(jobjh);

                 jobjt2.put("Cliente"+i++, list2);

            }
            listt.add(jobjt2);
            //Empleados
            String query3 = "select * from Empleados";
            rs = st.executeQuery(query3);
            i=0;
            while(rs.next()) {
                JSONArray list3 = new JSONArray();
                JSONObject jobja = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobjb = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobjc = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobjd = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobje = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobjf = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobjg = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobjh = new JSONObject();

                String c1 = rs.getString("Cod.Empleado");
                String c2 = rs.getString("Nombre");
                String c3 = rs.getString("Apellidos");
                String c4 = rs.getString("DNI");
                String c5 = rs.getString("Direccion");
                String c6 = rs.getString("FechaAlta");
                String c7 = rs.getString("CopiaContrato");
                String c8 = rs.getString("NCuenta");

                 jobja.put("codempleado", c1);
                 jobjb.put("nombre", c2);
                 jobjc.put("apellidos", c3);
                 jobjd.put("dni", c4);
                 jobje.put("direccion", c5);
                 jobjf.put("fechaalta", c6);
                 jobjg.put("copiacontrato", c7);
                 jobjh.put("numcuenta", c8);
                 list3.add(jobja);
                 list3.add(jobjb);
                 list3.add(jobjc);
                 list3.add(jobjd);
                 list3.add(jobje);
                 list3.add(jobjf);
                 list3.add(jobjg);
                 list3.add(jobjh);

                 jobjt3.put("Empleado"+i++, list3);

            }
            listt.add(jobjt3);
            //Existencias
            String query4 = "select * from Existencias";
            rs = st.executeQuery(query4);
            i=0;
            while(rs.next()) {
                JSONArray list4 = new JSONArray();
                JSONObject jobja = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobjb = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobjc = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobjd = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobje = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobjf = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobjg = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobjh = new JSONObject();

                String d1 = rs.getString("Cod.RefExistencia");
                String d2 = rs.getString("Cod.RefPro");
                String d3 = rs.getString("Cantidad");
                String d4 = rs.getString("Sitio");
                String d5 = rs.getString("Proposito");

                 jobja.put("codrefexistencia", d1);
                 jobjb.put("codrefproducto", d2);
                 jobjc.put("cantidad", d3);
                 jobjd.put("sitio", d4);
                 jobje.put("proposito", d5);
                 list4.add(jobja);
                 list4.add(jobjb);
                 list4.add(jobjc);
                 list4.add(jobjd);
                 list4.add(jobje);

                 jobjt4.put("Existencia"+i++, list4);

            }
            listt.add(jobjt4);
            //PedidosClientes
            String query5 = "select * from PedidosC";
            rs = st.executeQuery(query5);
            i=0;
            while(rs.next()) {
                JSONArray list5 = new JSONArray();
                JSONObject jobja = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobjb = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobjc = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobjd = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobje = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobjf = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobjg = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobjh = new JSONObject();

                String e1= rs.getString("NumPed");
                String e2= rs.getString("FechaPedido");
                String e3= rs.getString("FormadePago");
                String e4 = rs.getString("EnviadoA");
                String e5 = rs.getString("CodCliente");
                String e6 = rs.getString("CPP");

                 jobja.put("numped", e1);
                 jobjb.put("fechapedido", e2);
                 jobjc.put("formapago", e3);
                 jobjd.put("enviadoa", e4);
                 jobje.put("codcliente", e5);
                 jobjf.put("cpp", e6);
                 list5.add(jobja);
                 list5.add(jobjb);
                 list5.add(jobjc);
                 list5.add(jobjd);
                 list5.add(jobje);
                 list5.add(jobjf);

                 jobjt5.put("PedidoCliente"+i++, list5);

            }
            listt.add(jobjt5);
            //PedidosProveedores
            String query6 = "select * from PedidosP";
            rs = st.executeQuery(query6);
            i=0;
            while(rs.next()) {
                JSONArray list6 = new JSONArray();
                JSONObject jobja = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobjb = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobjc = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobjd = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobje = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobjf = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobjg = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobjh = new JSONObject();

                String f1= rs.getString("NumPed");
                String f2= rs.getString("FechaPedido");
                String f3 = rs.getString("FormadePago");
                String f4 = rs.getString("EnviadoA");
                String f5 = rs.getString("CodProv");
                String f6 = rs.getString("CPP");

                 jobja.put("numped", f1);
                 jobjb.put("fechapedido", f2);
                 jobjc.put("formapago", f3);
                 jobjd.put("enviadoa", f4);
                 jobje.put("codcliente", f5);
                 jobjf.put("cpp", f6);
                 list6.add(jobja);
                 list6.add(jobjb);
                 list6.add(jobjc);
                 list6.add(jobjd);
                 list6.add(jobje);
                 list6.add(jobjf);

                 jobjt6.put("PedidoProveedor"+i++, list6);

            }
            listt.add(jobjt6);
            //Productos
            String query7 = "select * from Productos";
            rs = st.executeQuery(query7);
            i=0;
            while(rs.next()) {
                JSONArray list7 = new JSONArray();
                JSONObject jobja = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobjb = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobjc = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobjd = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobje = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobjf = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobjg = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobjh = new JSONObject();

                String g1= rs.getString("Cod.RefPro");
                String g2= rs.getString("Nombre");
                String g3 = rs.getString("Descripcion");
                String g4 = rs.getString("PrecioNeto");
                String g5 = rs.getString("pvp");
                String g6 = rs.getString("CodRefProv");
                String g7 = rs.getString("Familia");
                String g8 = rs.getString("Existencias");

                 jobja.put("crf", g1);
                 jobjb.put("name", g2);
                 jobjc.put("desc", g3);
                 jobjd.put("pve", g4);
                 jobje.put("pvp", g5);
                 jobjf.put("cdp", g6);
                 jobjg.put("familia", g7);
                 jobjh.put("existencias", g8);
                 list7.add(jobja);
                 list7.add(jobjb);
                 list7.add(jobjc);
                 list7.add(jobjd);
                 list7.add(jobje);
                 list7.add(jobjf);
                 list7.add(jobjg);
                 list7.add(jobjh);

                 jobjt7.put("Producto"+i++, list7);


            }
            listt.add(jobjt7);
            //PropiaEmpresa
            String query8 = "select * from PropiaEmpresa";
            rs = st.executeQuery(query8);
            i=0;
            while(rs.next()) {
                JSONArray list8 = new JSONArray();
                JSONObject jobja = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobjb = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobjc = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobjd = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobje = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobjf = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobjg = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobjh = new JSONObject();

                String p1= rs.getString("CIF");
                String p2= rs.getString("RazonSocial");
                String p3 = rs.getString("Telefono");
                String p4 = rs.getString("Correo");
                String p5 = rs.getString("Direccion");
                String p6 = rs.getString("NCuenta");

                 jobja.put("cif", p1);
                 jobjb.put("razonsocial", p2);
                 jobjc.put("telef", p3);
                 jobjd.put("correo", p4);
                 jobje.put("direccion", p5);
                 jobjf.put("ncuenta", p6);
                 list8.add(jobja);
                 list8.add(jobjb);
                 list8.add(jobjc);
                 list8.add(jobjd);
                 list8.add(jobje);
                 list8.add(jobjf);

                 jobjt8.put("PropiaEmpresa", list8);

            }
            listt.add(jobjt8);
            //Proveedor
            String query9 = "select * from Proveedor";
            rs = st.executeQuery(query9);
            i=0;
            while(rs.next()) {
                JSONArray list9 = new JSONArray();
                JSONObject jobja = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobjb = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobjc = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobjd = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobje = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobjf = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobjg = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobjh = new JSONObject();

                String h1= rs.getString("Cod.Referencia");
                String h2= rs.getString("RazonSocial");
                String h3 = rs.getString("CIF");
                String h4 = rs.getString("Numero");
                String h5 = rs.getString("Correo");
                String h6 = rs.getString("Direccion");
                String h7 = rs.getString("MetodoPago");
                String h8 = rs.getString("Observaciones");

                 jobja.put("crf", h1);
                 jobjb.put("razonsocial", h2);
                 jobjc.put("cif", h3);
                 jobjd.put("num", h4);
                 jobje.put("correo", h5);
                 jobjf.put("direccion", h6);
                 jobjg.put("metodopago", h7);
                 jobjh.put("observaciones", h8);
                 list9.add(jobja);
                 list9.add(jobjb);
                 list9.add(jobjc);
                 list9.add(jobjd);
                 list9.add(jobje);
                 list9.add(jobjf);
                 list9.add(jobjg);
                 list9.add(jobjh);

                 jobjt9.put("Proveedor"+i++, list9);

            }
            listt.add(jobjt9);
            routes router = new routes();
            String ruta = router.getruta();

            try (FileWriter file = new FileWriter(ruta+"data.json")) {
                file.write(listt.toJSONString());
                file.flush();
            }
        }catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error: "+ex);
        }
    }

}
```

I try to almost read the file with this code and the parse it but I dont get it.

```
    import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.*;
import org.json.*;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class parse {
routes router = new routes();
String ruta = router.getruta();
    public parse() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void parseproductos() {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        try {final Scanner sc = new Scanner( new File("N:\\data.json"), "UTF-8" )) {
            final String fileContents = sc.useDelimiter("\\A").next();
            parser.parse(fileContents);
//as ccjmne sugested

        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) { e.printStackTrace();}
        catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace();}
        catch (ParseException e) { e.printStackTrace();}
        catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace();}
        } 
    }
```

I tried it and I only get errors. And instead parsing it I get errors of permissions reading the file or other ones. How can I improve the code and parsing? It is for a school project.

### Update

Thanks to ccjmne for the sugested changes, did and the errors finished. Now my problem returns to the main problem, I don't know how to read the nested json arrays and put them on an java array.

Comment: Your code is kinda messy~~. Really tiresome to read all of it

Comment: You call a toString() method on a FileReader object then try to parse that string. Is that ok?

Comment: I suggest you ask the update section as a new question, and then remove that section from this question. One problem per post please (and no deadline/urgency pleading - most folks are volunteers here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that's because you're not attempting to parse the contents of your file, but the result of `new FileReader(...).toString()`, which does something different entirely.

You'll have to actually read the contents in the first place :)

For example:

```
//                                              try and specify the charset if possible
//                                                             v     v
try(final Scanner sc = new Scanner( new File("N:\\data.json"), "UTF-8" )) {
    final String fileContents = sc.useDelimiter("\\A").next();
    parser.parse(fileContents);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Yeah but my main problem persists, I dont know how to parse a nested arrays

Answer (score 0):

Calling `toString()` on a `FileReader` object will give you something like this: `java.io.FileReader@2345345` and you try to parse this string, that is why the error message says that you have an unexpected 'j' character at position 0. Try to read that json file first, then parse.

Comment: Now I have the problem to parse it